# Rabbitmq keeps crashing - Reason: Completed

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, helm

I am running a rabbitmq inside Kubernetes cluster using Bitnami chart. And if often crashes with no other reason than "Completed". Prior migration to k8s, Rabbit was working fine as one of the crucial parts of our infrastructure. Now it does not work reliably.

- Kube cluster version: `1.28.2-do.0` (running in Digital Ocean)
- Helm chart: [bitnamicharts/rabbitmq](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/rabbitmq)
- Chart version: `12.14.0`
- Helm version: `v3.14.1`

Used `values.yaml`

```yaml
# Configure auth to keep same password and use different username
auth:
  username: rabbit
  existingPasswordSecret: rabbitmq-credentials

metrics:
  enabled: true

  serviceMonitor:
    enabled: true
    labels:
      release: kube-prometheus-stack


resources:
  requests:
    cpu: 1
    memory: 512Mi
  limits:
    cpu: 2
    memory: 2048Mi
```

Install command

```
helm upgrade --install rabbitmq -n utils --values values.yml oci://registry-1.docker.io/bitnamicharts/rabbitmq --version 12.14.0
```

`kubectl get pod`

```
rabbitmq-0                   0/1     Completed   0          41h
```

`kubectl describe po rabbitmq-0`

```
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Tue, 19 Mar 2024 19:04:50 +0000
      Finished:     Tue, 19 Mar 2024 20:33:22 +0000
```

`kubectl logs rabbitmq-0`

```
unable to retrieve container logs for containerd://3000a11229497c5441483040153f2d07bde0b4aaca472486a09241c3d37002f6
```

`kubectl get events`

```
No resources found in traders-utils namespace.
```

Resources usage in Grafana
[image: resources usage]

What should be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to this related [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69567270/rabbitmq-pod-is-crashing-unexpectedly) as it seems that you are experiencing the same concern. As per Jehof, he was recommending adding additional resources to the pod to avoid OOM. Same with this article by [acurrent](https://thwack.solarwinds.com/products/network-performance-monitor-npm/f/forum/88282/rabbit-mq-crash#:%7E:text=RabbitMQ%20crashes%20periodically%20due%20to,than%2090%25%20at%20the%20time.), which they are referring the cause of an unexpected rabbitmq crash.

Comment: Thanks for message Dion, I will go through both articles, but I have slight doubt about resources exhaustion. I have added charts from Grafana and the rabbitmq barery touches 150 MiB, even though the limit is 13x times higher. However I will monitor this.